# Equivalent for SSE in Power PC

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, powerpc, altivec

What is the equivalent for SSE instruction set on Power PC? Is it Altivec?
Does anyone have any samples for migrating SSE instructions to Power PC?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Altivec is the PowerPC's SIMD (vector) instruction set. You can Google for manuals as I did, e.g. [vector_simd_pem.ppc.2005AUG23.pdf](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/vector_simd_pem.ppc.2005AUG23.pdf), and Google `sse to altivec howto` for resources such as this: [Intel SSE to PowerPC AltiVec migration](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W51a7ffcf4dfd_4b40_9d82_446ebc23c550/page/Intel%20SSE%20to%20PowerPC%20AltiVec%20migration).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. I was checked the SSE to Altivec migration guide, but don't seem to find any mapping for SSE4 instruction pcmpestrm. Any idea on how this instruction can be ported to Power PC?

Comment: AltiVec doesn't really have anything corresponding to the SSE string instructions - you'll need to roll your own implementation for these.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Simd Library](http://simd.sourceforge.net/). It has many algorithms (mainly image processing) which optimized with using of different SIMD:  SSE, SSE2, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX and AVX2 for x86/x64, VMX(Altivec) and VSX(Power7) for PowerPC, NEON for ARM. I hope that these samples will be usefull for you.

Answer (score 1):

Apple produced a very useful guide for AltiVec to SSE migration a few years back - I can't see it on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) any more, but it's easy enough to find archived copies, e.g. [this one](http://www.thomasdideriksen.dk/misc/SIMD/Accelerate_sse_migration.pdf). You can use this guide "in reverse" to migrate from SSE to AltiVec.

Note also that if you search StackOverflow for anything with the [altivec](/questions/tagged/altivec) tag you should find a number of useful questions and answers about converting between SSE and AltiVec SIMD code.